# How can i add an event to jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I know this (**first**):

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Therefor i can write (**second**):

```
$("#target").kendoButton({
    click: function(e) {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    }
...
```

How could i now add a "[focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)" event to **second** ?

Thx for answer !

Comment: I am not familiarized with kendo, but *maybe* you can do something like `$("#target").kendoButton({ /*...*/}).on('blur', function(){ /* your staff here */ });`

Comment: kendo doesn't expose all event handler to jQuery and it's has different for event each widget, please check kendo button event here and looks like it doesn't have blur event , thus you may need to create a custom binder or bind an event to the element

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the explanation on my comment, this is how you create/extend kendo widget event like this :

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.onBlur = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function (element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
        var binding = this.bindings.onBlur;
        $(element.input).bind("blur", function (e) {
            binding.get();
            return false;
        });
    },
    refresh: function () {}
});
```

Create a kendo widget to the element

```
var button = $("#button").kendoButton({
    enable: true,
});
```

Then bind the element that associated with a kendo widget with the event

```
button.bind("blur", function(e) {
    alert("YOLO");
});
```

You can see it in action, first click the button then clik outside(on blur) event will trigerred

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cvmzfma8/)

Comment: Hmm, i want someting like this if it´s possible...

http://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/ccv29w7k/

Comment: As far i know that wouldnt work as my comment above by default kendo button doesnt have focusout event therefore you cant do that, but i may be wrong though. You can try to look at kendo documentation for kendo button.